# Can I localize AFX_IDP_ASK_TO_SAVE?

Tags: c++, mfc, localization

In my application, I have a 'Do you want to save your changes?' message box. I'm getting the text to display from MFC:

```
CString prompt;
AfxFormatString1(prompt, AFX_IDP_ASK_TO_SAVE, strFileName);
UINT nResult = AfxMessageBox(prompt, MB_YESNOCANCEL, AFX_IDP_ASK_TO_SAVE)
```

Now I'm localizing the application to Japanese. I'm guessing that standard texts such as this are already translated to most of the major languages. But I have no idea how to set MFC to use the Japanese versions of the resource identifiers of these standard texts. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Maybe check the sources to see if there is a changeable localization variable?

Comment: Disclaimer: ad ahead. Please skip this comment if you don't want to read it! [appTranslator](http://www.apptranslator.com) is a great tool to help you translate your app and manage the localization process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I needed to change a few include files in my .rc file:

```
#include "afxres.rc"         // Standard components
#include "afxprint.rc"               // printing/print preview resources
#include "afxribbon.rc"              // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
```

needed to become:

```
#include "l.jpn/afxres.rc"         // Standard components
#include "l.jpn/afxprint.rc"               // printing/print preview resources
#include "l.jpn/afxribbon.rc"              // MFC ribbon and control bar resources
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008 AFX_IDP_ASK_TO_SAVE and other AFX_... strings are kept in MFC localization DLLs: MFC90CHS.dll, MFC90JPN.dll. MFC90KOR.dll etc. To use them on Windows Vista and later you should call:

```
SetThreadUILanguage (MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US));
```

or

```
SetThreadUILanguage (MAKELANGID(LANG_JAPANESE,SUBLANG_JAPANESE_JAPAN));
```

on Windows XP call:

```
SetThreadLocale(lcid)
```

For constants refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Use GetSystemDefaultLangID to retrieve right locale i.e. on Chinese OS.

**Important:** don't use GetUserDefaultLangID() or GetSystemDefaultUILanguage(), they return different things, i.e. in case you have English OS, having Chinese locale selected.

```
lcid = MAKELCID(GetSystemDefaultLangID(), SORT_DEFAULT);//With Chinese locale, returns 0x804, zh-CN
```